# Optional Parameter in API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, api, parameters, optional-parameters

I am running an API controller in MVC with C #, I want to consume this web service from an App in Xamarin after ...

In my GET method of the controller I need to capture the parameter ROL or the parameter Patent .... or Well the two together

I only work with the 2 parameters together !! Entering ROL and Patent brings me the corresponding Municipal Patent ...

What I want is for the user to enter 1 (ROL or Patent) or the 2 parameters (Role and Patent) and work the same

I have tried with if ... and I do not give with success
Any help for me?

[When I consult 2 parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJwDc.png)
[When I consult 1 parameters (ROL o Patente)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVg0o.png)

```
  // GET: api/PatenteMunicipalsAPI/ROL/Patente
        [ResponseType(typeof(PatenteMunicipal))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPatenteMunicipal(string id, string param2)
        {

            var patenteMunicipal = db.PatenteMunicipals.ToList().
                Where(u => u.ROL == id && u.Patente == param2).
                FirstOrDefault();                    

            return Ok(patenteMunicipal);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways.  The first method is to take advantage of the fact that Linq doesn't actually execute until you try to access to results (e.g. ToList(), FirstOrDefault() etc.) so you can build up your query in pieces as follows;

```
//Make sure we have at least one parameter so we don't return all table rows
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("At least one parameter must be provided");

//Create the base query but don't execute
var query = from pm in Db.PatenteMunicipals select pm;

//Add the where clause for id if provided
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)
      query = query.Where(x => x.ROL == id);

//Add the where clause for param2 is provided
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2)
      query = query.Where(x => x.Patente == param2);

//Now force the query to execute and return results
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
return Ok(result);
```

The other alternative, if your requirements get a lot more complex is to use System.Linq.Dynamic which is available as a Nuget package which allows you to create the where clause as a string.  You can then build the where clause string up in code before executing the linq statement but that's probably overkill for what you need here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: First thanks for the quick response, secondly explain that from this API are exposed variables to be consumed in the web service of my Mobile App, I put their code in my Get method and there are no changes, the worst is that I check with "POSTMAN "I still have success when I consult two parameters ... and requiring only one (ROL or Patent) ... this brings me all the data ...


Any suggestions? @Tintow

Comment: Hi Cristofher, I don't understand how you are getting a response with multiple results because you are using FirstOrDefault which can only return a single item.  Are you sure you have posted the full code for the method?